# How to stop people accessing hidden pages where a login is required?

Tags: php, html, session

I am doing a project in school, I need to know a simple way to stop poeple from entering the site without a session. I have alot of pages I don't believe I spent the time pasting code on every page. Also I have menu bar that is included in every page thanks to php, so i was wondering wat type of code would I have to put in the menu to block user without a session. The rest of the content code is on the pages that I want to hide. I believe that you can login by typing out the url and allow users to see hidden pages that are for logged in users.

Comment: Just remember if the user is logged in with a session variable. Check this variable at the beginning of every web page. If it's not set, redirect to the login page.

Comment: well I understand that if i put that in my menubar which is link to every page would it still work

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop people from getting to website without logging in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426059/how-to-stop-people-from-getting-to-website-without-logging-in)

Answer (score 4):

Please do not use a plain cookie. Sessions are the way to go. Or if can't use sessions and must use a cookie, sign the cookies first to be able to verify that your application was really the one to set it.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['authenticated'])) {
  header('Location: login.php');
  exit; 
}

... whatever logged in users should see ..
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use session, then use cookie.

```
<?php
/*Just add this piece of PHP code to top of any page you 
   don't want not-logged in users to see */
if (!isset($_COOKIE['logged']))
    header("Location: login.php");  //It redirects the user to your login page

?>

<html>
   <body>
      ...
   </body>
</html>
```

Login page could be like this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_COOKIE['logged']))
        header("home.php");

    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        //get username and password
        $uname = $_POST['uname'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];

        if ($uname=="correct" && $pass=="correct"){ //EDIT
            setcookie('logged','1');
                    header("Location: home.php"); //Redirect to home page
        }
        else echo "Wrong combinaton!";
    }

?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <label>Username</label><input type="text" name="uname" /><br />
            <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="pass" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there any way to do this with sessions

Comment: Yes. That is simple as well. After you have verified username and password start session writing `session_start();` And then set session variable as `$_SESSION['logged']=1`. And then instead of checking the cookie you check if the session variable has been set. `session_start(); if (isset($_SESSION['logged'])) ...`.

Comment: This is really insecure. to log in you just need to create cookie "logged". You wouldn't need the username or password at all.

Comment: @bencoder But the user can't see from the client side that they can. It's not like they can get to the PHP source.

Comment: @MrLister - That's security by obscurity. It's a very bad idea.

Comment: @Alohci Let's just agree to disagree. My take is that, for a hacker, guessing the cookie name would be just as time consuming as guessing a username and password on the site.